# using the terminal to copy files to a dynamically created folder

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to use mac's terminal to copy files from one directory to another, where the second directory is based on the date:

```
cp -Rp /path/from/* /first part of path to/$(date '+%m')_$(date '+%d')_$(date '+%Y')/second part of path to/
```

The date piece is giving me some grief, I fear.  Is there a way that I can create a dynamic path with the date as such?

Thank you...